# How to figure out the length of the result of `fmt::format` without running it?

Tags: c++, fmt

While answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70109997/how-to-format-an-2d-array-of-different-type-sized-strings-e-g-x-xxx-xx-xxx/70110333#70110333) question about printing a 2D array of strings into a table, I realized:

I haven't found a better way to determine the length of the result of a `fmt::format` call that to actually format into a string and check the length of that string.

Is that by design, or is there a more efficient way to go about that? I don't know the internals of fmtlib all too well, but I imagine, the length of the result is known before memory allocation happens. I'd especially like to avoid the memory allocation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Straight from the [API documentation](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#_CPPv4IDpEN3fmt14formatted_sizeE6size_t13format_stringIDp1TEDpRR1T):

> ```cpp
> template<typename ...T>  
> auto fmt::formatted_size(format_string<T...> fmt, T&&... args) -> size_t
> ```
>
> Returns the number of chars in the output of `format(fmt, args...)`.